# Facebook callback response not accepted

Tags: php, facebook

The description of the problem I'm having is EXACTLY as it's described in this posting: [Credits callback script not called (error 1383046)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166977/credits-callback-script-not-called-error-1383046)

I was going to respond to that specific posting, however, this site says not to do that, so I'm creating a new thread.

My description is exactly as described in this other posters claim, but I don't have a .htaccess file.

I can see that Facebook is calling my callback file (.php) - twice - but, it still gives me an error: "Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again."

I setup the callback to return this canned response (which looks properly formatted to me) and this doesn't work.

```
{"content":[{"title":"10000 Game Credits","description":"Credits used for playing the games","price":5,"image_url":"http:\/\/www.egamestudio.com\/fbslot\/Coin.png","product_url":"http:\/\/www.egamestudio.com\/fbslot\/Coin.png","item_id":"newcash","order_id":"1a"}],"method":"payments_get_items"}
```

A couple questions:
1. Does it matter if you're in sandbox mode or not (I've tried both and it doesn't make a difference, but I'd like it clarified)
2. Do you have to be signed up with TrialPay or something else for this to work and maybe that's causing the issue?
3. Am I missing an oauth token that may be necessary or something along the lines of a security piece missing?

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: The callback being called twice is one call and a second retry, then it fails - the response you're giving isn't valid as far as Facebook is concerned - try to simulate the request facebook makes and examine the response carefully to make sure you're definitely sending what you think you are

Comment: @Igy : Why not post that as an answer so we can upvote it?  :)

Comment: I didn't think that was really an answer - i'm really just re-stating the symptom and asking him to check carefully :)

Comment: I hard-coded the response as shown in the post. I also pulled the file directly (the response) with a file_get_contents and received the same data: {"content":[{"title":"10000 Game Credits","description":"Credits used for playing the games","price":5,"image_url":"http:\/\/www.egamestudio.com\/fbslot\/Coin.png","product_url":"http:\/\/www.egamestudio.com\/fbslot\/Coin.png","item_id":"newcash","order_id":"1a"}],"method":"payments_get_items"}.There isn't anything special that needs to be done with the header content-types or something like that? I'm using charset:UTF-8.

Comment: Are there any development conditions that would prevent the response from being accepted? For example, a setting in the fb development pages that I might not have set correctly?

Comment: Is there a 'simulator' that would allow me to submit the callback page so I can see what Facebook is seeing that might help me to figure out what is causing the problem?